# How to get a timestamp in format YYMMDDHHMMSSNNN

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, timestamp

I am upgrading an application that sends SOAP requests to a web-service. The new web-service has some strongly typed fields and one of them 'TimeStamp' has the below definition:

```
array          false 
mandatory      true 
output         false 
input          true 
xsdType        xsd:long 
Length  
Values  
maxVal         990101000000000 
minVal         131105100000000 
nativeFormat   9999999999999999 
default None 
description    Balance TimeStamp YYMMDDHHMMSSNNN
```

so I have tried the below but I cannot get it right and throws an exception **"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**:

```
 wsSoapBody.TimeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.ParseExact _
(DateTime.Now, "YYMMDDHHMMSSNNN",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

So what am I missing or getting wrong here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert a date into the mentioned format, `ParseExact` isnt necessary. It is used to parse a string in the given format into a `DateTime`. For your problem you just need:

```
Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Answer (score 3):

Format of time string is case sensitive

```
 wsSoapBody.TimeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.ParseExact _
   (DateTime.Now, "yyMMddHHmmssfff",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: 3 upvotes? o.O Why? This doesn't even compile. `DateTime.Now` returns `DateTime`, not `string`. Are you sure you know what _parsing_ means exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for pointing it out, you are right, was to focus on the time format and didn't notice the first parameter is not in string, tq.